# "MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax" on Java SQL

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mariadb

I am trying to connect a Java program with a MariaDB through PhpMyAdmin on Eclipse Enterprise. I get this annoying error all the time, even though the database seems to be connected:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'Order ( OrderId INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  address
> VARCHAR(20),  dt DA...' at line 1

Here is my code:

```java
package main;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // db parameters
            String url       = "jdbc:mysql://ip_number:3307/test_db";
            String user      = "root";
            String password  = "root";
            // create a connection to the database  
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connected!");
            
            stmt =  conn.createStatement();
            String sqlCreate = 
                     "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Order (" +
                     " OrderId INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                     " address VARCHAR(20), " + 
                     " dt DATE, " + 
                     " status VARCHAR(20), " + 
                     " PRIMARY KEY('OrderId'))"; 

            stmt.execute(sqlCreate);
            System.out.println("Created Order-table in given database..."); 
            
        } catch(SQLException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try{
                   if(conn != null)
                   {
                     conn.close();
                   }
            }catch(SQLException ex){
                   System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have watched everywhere on the web and on this site and corrected the syntax many times. I am also sure, that the syntax is correct, because, if I query direct the database on phpMyAdmin, the table is created. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Order` is a reserved word.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is a web application query tool for MySQL/MariaDB. Your Java application does not connect _"through PhpMyAdmin"_. It connects directly to MariaDB. I would also recommend you learn about [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), as it will simplify your code.